# How to set the id of a model on Odoo, using Odoo API(Odoo 13)?

Tags: api, odoo

I've created products(model product.template), using Odoo API but when I tried setting the product.template's id, Odoo didn't let me and set the id with a value generated by the system.

```
final Integer id = (Integer)models.execute("execute_kw", Arrays.asList(
                        db, uid, password,
                        "product.template", "create",
                        Arrays.asList(new HashMap() {{ 
                                                       put("is_published", true);
                                                       put("active", true);
                                                       put("x_standartization_level", article.getStandartizationLevel());
                                                       put("id", Integer.valueOf(article.getMfsIdentifier()));
```

Comment: Why do you need to set the `ìd` manually?

Comment: The web service creates products(product.template) on Odoo. For each product there are related products. So, in product.template i created field related_product, the type - many2many, referencing product.template. When the service creates a product, at the same time, i need to set the related products, to set the join table with the id of the current product and the ids of its related products.

Comment: You can check your previous question, You will use a special command to write the value to `related_product` field.